# ClearDB Granting Created User Access

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, permissions

I added the ClearDB addon to Heroku, but upon using the created username to create a new database, the error appeared:

```
Executing:
CREATE SCHEMA `androidchatterdatabase` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;

Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
ERROR 1044: Access denied for user 'bcb4810d4a34ac'@'%' to database 'androidchatterdatabase'
SQL Statement:
CREATE SCHEMA `androidchatterdatabase` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8
```

Viewing the GRANTS for this user, it notes:

[image]

Given the readout notes on database heroku_09ace026abf6348, I have `ALL PRIVILIEDGES`

Attempting to access the Users and Privileges tab to alter the user, the below returns:

[image]

At present, I am stuck.

How can I alter the access so I can create a database?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21976/discussion-between-nawaz-sohail-and-sauron).

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but never answered. 
The correct answer is that ClearDB does not allow certain functionality on  multi-tenant cluster, including create database, views, UDF's and triggers.

You would need to upgrade to a dedicated cluster in order to perform this statement.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL Workbench doesn't allow you to modify for some reason but I've managed to gain access to it through Navicat.

Comment: This answer would be better if it described how to manipulate Navicat to achieve this.